# host skewed by 37 sec, XDMP-CLOCKSKEW

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

After changing expanded tree cache configuration, cluster restarted and for one of the host forest got disabled atomatically. Error is XDMP-CLOCKSKEW. Now forest has no enable button. Any idea how to handle it.

Comment: Have you looked at the time across all your hosts? This is saying the cluster times aren’t in sync.

Comment: Yes @hunterhacker, One node is ahead by 37 sec than other two. Now would like to set time (current time - 37 sec) to sync with other two.

Comment: @hunterhacker, it is up now. Thanks much..!!

Comment: Cool, I'll make it a formal answer to earn the magical green checkmark of acceptance.

Comment: Yeah sure @hunterhacker

Comment: Are you running on VMs or bare metal?  If they are VMs, there may be additional settings that need to be changed for NTP to work correctly

Answer (score 3):

An XDMP-CLOCKSKEW error indicates the hosts in a MarkLogic cluster have times that are no longer synchronized.  I'd recommend using NTP to keep the times in sync.  Here's a KB article on the topic:

https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/24/15/synchronizing-system-clocks-in-a-cluster